# adding rows dynamically in classic asp and giving the connection to the new rows to database

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, oracle11g

I am just a beginer in asp and i have a problem. I have a common function which add rows dynamically and the code is as follows

```
function Myfunction(tableid) 
{

var table=document.getElementById("tablerow");        

var rowCount = table.rows.length;        

var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);        


var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); 

cell1.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;


var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

var element2 = document.createElement("input");

cell2.appendChild(element2);


var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

var element3 = document.createElement("input");

cell3.appendChild(element3);


var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

var element4 = document.createElement("input");

cell4.appendChild(element4);

}
```

And the AddPage code of html is as follows:

```
"table id="tablerow"

tr align="center"

input type="textbox" name="subjectid"

input type="textbox" name="subjectname"

input type="Checkbox" name="status"  value="Y"

input type="Checkbox" name="status"  value="N"

input type="textbox" name="internal"

input type="textbox" name="external"

tr
```

And an insert query as follows:

```
sql1="INSERT INTO SUBJECT_MASTER (SUBJECT_ID,SUBJECT_NAME,ACTIVE_STATUS,INTERNAL,EXTERNAL) VALUES ("&subjectid & ",'" &subjectname &"','"&activestatus &"','"&internal &"','"&external &"')"
```

Now if i add a row and insert the data using the new added rows, It is not inserting the data. So please can you help me.And also Please also clear me the checkbox issue.

Comment: thank you brother. i will see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic ASP read the form data based on the elements **name** - each element send its value based on its name. Without a name, the value won't be sent to the server at all.

So to  have the newly added elements send their value, simply give them a name. Assuming you want same name as your existing text boxes:

```
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var element2 = document.createElement("input");
element2.name = "subjectid"
cell2.appendChild(element2);

var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var element3 = document.createElement("input");
element3.name = "subjectname"
cell3.appendChild(element3);
```

This way the values will be sent as comma separated string.

**IMPORTANT**: your current code is wide open for SQL injection attacks. If you don't want your database to be hacked, copied and/or deleted you better learn about SQL injection (just Google it) and fix your code.

Comment: Sir, Can you tell how to add a row with checkbox?

Comment: Assuming the code you posted is working just have it executed on the checkbox click event.